# Why isn't this static project page showing up on a Jekyll-generated user page on GitHub Pages?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I have a [user page](https://github.com/nimizuela/nimizuela.github.io) generated with Jekyll, it works fine, it even has a 404 custom page. But now I'd like to have a [project page](https://github.com/nimizuela/jspaint/tree/gh-pages) that is just plain HTML, CSS and JavaScript (no Node.js nor Jekyll), showing up as `my_acount.github.io/project_repo/`. I uploaded the content, added a blank file with the name `.nojekyll`, and created a duplicate branch with the name `gh-pages` which is the one selected in the settings for GitHub Pages, but when I visit `https://my_acount.github.io/project_repo/` the browser shows a 404 page that is not the custom page for `https://my_acount.github.io`, and the content in the `index.html` page in `project_repo` is not shown.

Is it posible to have a configuration to show my project page hosted as a subfolder of the user page, without having to add it as a submodule or subfolder to the user website repository? If so, why isn't my configuration working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that github pages doesn't publish by default.

I succeeded to publish by doing :

- fork https://github.com/1j01/jspaint
- go to repo **settings** (https://github.com/username/reponame/settings)
- in **GitHub Pages** section, switch source list to **master branch** and click save.
- switch back to **gh-pages branch** and click save

Project is now published.

Comment: That was it! Thank you. It's very much appreciated.